# process[rosout-1] keeps repeating

Tags: turtlebot, ros-hydro, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Followed the tutorial up till turtlebot bringup. (apparently i dont have enough karma to post links)

Managed to SSH into the turtle bot laptop, then I tried the turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch and these came out on the terminal non stop

```
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [7331]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
```

Help?

Workstation is running ROS Indigo while the turtlebot laptop is running ROS hydro.
Will different version of ROS complicate things? Or did I messed up somewhere during the installation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187511/process%5Brosout-1%5D-keeps-repeating/) by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2014-07-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you don't have your locale set properly.

You may want to take a look at the Ubuntu page about generating locale files: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale

Or just try setting your locale to the generic `C` locale (named for the C programming language):

```
sudo update-locale LANG=C LANGUAGE=C LC_ALL=C LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [charkoteow](https://answers.ros.org/users/19824/charkoteow/) on 2014-07-24**:
export LC_ALL="C" seems to do the trick for me.
thank you!